# R: how do split a delimited columns(state) into columns with a binary 1,0

Tags: r, split, dplyr, tidyr

Appreciate your help. Need to split a column filled with delimited values into columns named after its delimited values and each of these new columns are to be filled with either 1 or 0 where values are found or not.

```
state <- 
  c('ACT',
    'ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|SA|VIC',
    'ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|TAS|VIC|WA',
    'ACT|NSW|NT|SA|TAS|VIC',
    'ACT|NSW|QLD|VIC',
    'ACT|NSW|SA',
    'ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|TAS|VIC|WA|SA',
    'NSW',
    'NT',
    'NT|SA',
    'QLD',
    'SA',
    'TAS',
    'VIC',
    'WA')

df <- data.frame(id = 1:length(state),state)

id                        state
1   1                          ACT
2   2        ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|SA|VIC
3   3    ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|TAS|VIC|WA
4   4        ACT|NSW|NT|SA|TAS|VIC
...
```

Desired state is a dataframe with the same dimensions plus the additional columns based on state populated with a 1 or 0 depending on the rows.

tq,
James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    separate_rows(state) %>% 
    unique() %>%            # in case you have duplicated states for a single id
    mutate(exist = 1) %>% 
    spread(state, exist, fill=0)

#   id ACT NSW NT QLD SA TAS VIC WA
#1   1   1   0  0   0  0   0   0  0
#2   2   1   1  1   1  1   0   1  0
#3   3   1   1  1   1  0   1   1  1
#4   4   1   1  1   0  1   1   1  0
#5   5   1   1  0   1  0   0   1  0
#6   6   1   1  0   0  1   0   0  0
#7   7   1   1  1   1  1   1   1  1
#8   8   0   1  0   0  0   0   0  0
#9   9   0   0  1   0  0   0   0  0
#10 10   0   0  1   0  1   0   0  0
#11 11   0   0  0   1  0   0   0  0
#12 12   0   0  0   0  1   0   0  0
#13 13   0   0  0   0  0   1   0  0
#14 14   0   0  0   0  0   0   1  0
#15 15   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  1
```

- `separate_rows` split `state` and convert the data frame to long format;
- add a constant value column for reshaping purpose;
- use `spread` to transform the result to wide format;

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option to split the 'state' column by `|`, convert the `list` of vectors into a two column `data.frame` (`stack`), get the frequency with `table` and `cbind` with the first column of 'df'

```
cbind(df[1], as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$state), 
                   "[|]"), df$id))[2:1])))
#   id ACT NSW NT QLD SA TAS VIC WA
#1   1   1   0  0   0  0   0   0  0
#2   2   1   1  1   1  1   0   1  0
#3   3   1   1  1   1  0   1   1  1
#4   4   1   1  1   0  1   1   1  0
#5   5   1   1  0   1  0   0   1  0
#6   6   1   1  0   0  1   0   0  0
#7   7   1   1  1   1  1   1   1  1
#8   8   0   1  0   0  0   0   0  0
#9   9   0   0  1   0  0   0   0  0
#10 10   0   0  1   0  1   0   0  0
#11 11   0   0  0   1  0   0   0  0
#12 12   0   0  0   0  1   0   0  0
#13 13   0   0  0   0  0   1   0  0
#14 14   0   0  0   0  0   0   1  0
#15 15   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  1
```